# Typescript: type one parameter based on the other

Tags: typescript

See this playground: [Playground](http://www.typescriptlang.org/play/index.html#code/KYDwDg9gTgLgBASwHY2FAZgQwMbDgSQAUoIATAV23gG8AoOBuMEiq-UgLjiXIFsAjNAG5aAX1q1QkWIhRosuAgGEIvMJiQBPOHUZxsq9VvZceA4WInpySKgghJ9AGwTYA1gAoYmsMC4ByZjJKGH8AGjhgFARvLiIWEIBKLgBnGChkAHMRa1sYe0dsF3cvHz84fwM1DU1wyOjY5UMa5Lg0jKRs2ly7B2dXNwAeABUAPlLfAKDWULgAHwqqo1qIqPzG4cSdekYEdDgJvABeE4rpkP8t3T1GKGAYcihHQISqCrgAanr1zQA6c7YpBEelEkScKTwewO3l8cBOR0WzS0l22N1u90ezyWNXeXzWMT+2OMQJ2DHEpLgMAAFiQAO7cYD0gCiUBIUA8-lpJE6sjA5FCiRE5KKAw5ANCEWoTFeMBMcAAjAAmADMcFEgqAA)

```
export interface IProduct {
    productId: number;
}

export interface ICompany {
    companyId: number;
}

function click(type: 'product', entity: IProduct): string;
function click(type: 'company', entity: ICompany): string;
function click<T>(type: 'product' | 'company', entity: T) {
    if (type === 'product') {
        return 'product ' + entity.productId;
    } else if (type === 'company') {
        return 'company ' + entity.companyId;
    }

    throw new Error('wrong input');
}

click('product', { productId: 123 });
```

How do I make typescript understand, that if the first if evaluates true, then the second argument is an `IProduct`?

Comment: How about using `return 'product ' + entity["productId"];` as you know here what type parameter to look here and fetch?

Answer (score 2):

You could type arguments as union of tuples, but it is ugly because destructuring can't be used (typescript will loose type relation):

```
function click(type: 'product', entity: IProduct): string;
function click(type: 'company', entity: ICompany): string;
function click(...args: ['product', IProduct] | ['company', ICompany]) {
    if (args[0] === 'product') {
        return 'product ' + args[1].productId;
    } else if (args[0] === 'company') {
        return 'company ' + args[1].companyId;
    }

    throw new Error('wrong input');
}
```

[Playground](http://www.typescriptlang.org/play/index.html#code/KYDwDg9gTgLgBASwHY2FAZgQwMbDgSQAUoIATAV23gG8AoOBuMEiq-UgLjiXIFsAjNAG5aAX1qhIsRCjRZcBAMIReYTEgCecOozjYVazey48BwsbVrpySKgghI9AGwTYA1gAoYGsMC4ByZjJKGH8AGjhgFARvLiIWEIBKLgBnGChkAHMRa1sYe0dsF3cvHz84f31VdQ1wyOjYpQMa5Lg0jKRsqxs7B2dXTwA6YcwoTJSuAG1AhKo6+OCqAF04AB84aarDWoj8ZWrNJcTtekYEdDgPUfHJgAYVgF4niqDWUOOdXUYoYBhyKEcM0W8H8cAA1HBrilJgBGJaDV4hdgiXSiSJOFJ4c6XKF3R7PSrNTT+D6nL5wH5-AEVLY1CrgyFjaFwwa0oykFGMcRkuAwAAWJAA7txgMKAKJQEhQDz+QUkToyMDkd4ibkAejVcAAKnyECk4IKHP54IaoG5hrQNXBcr1CsVPJNvL4IlF8t4llMgW95sRgSt1psiTsmgcNEdLEUBjLEXMItQmLMYMY4DCAEwAZjgokSQiAA)

Comment: if we know the exact attribute to look at when you need to match the specific type then why not keep it simple to something like `return 'product ' + entity["productId"]` ?

Comment: @Sohan because this won't work with `noImplicitAny` (`entity.productId` is the same as `entity["productId"]`). [Try](http://www.typescriptlang.org/play/index.html#code/KYDwDg9gTgLgBASwHY2FAZgQwMbDgSQAUoIATAV23gG8AoOBuMEiq-UgLjiXIFsAjNAG5aAX1q1QkWIhRosuAgGEIvMJiQBPOHUZxsq9VvZceA4WInpySKgghJ9AGwTYA1gAoYmsMC4ByZjJKGH8AGjhgFARvLiIWEIBKLgBnGChkAHMRa1sYe0dsF3cvHz84fwM1DU1wyOjY5UMa5Lg0jKRs2ly7B2dXT29fAKDWULgAHwqqo1qIqPzG+OCqSabqrUSdekYEdDhS3zgAXlOK0ZD-Ld09RihgGHIoR0CE1f84AGp6xc0AbQARBc2KQAQBdER6USRJwpPB7A5DPCnY7TZpaK7bW53B5PF4zGoVL4-GL-AEE4ygiE7BjiGlwGAACxIAHduMA2QBRKAkKAefwskidWRgcihRIiURAA)

Answer (score 0):

### A working solution (but not a good one):

```js
function click(type: 'product', entity: IProduct): string;
function click(type: 'company', entity: ICompany): string;
function click<T extends IProduct | ICompany>(type: 'product' | 'company', entity: T) {
    if (type === 'product' && assertType(type, entity)) {
        return 'product ' + entity.productId;
    } else if (type === 'company' && assertType(type, entity)) {
        return 'company ' + entity.companyId;
    }

    throw new Error('wrong input');
}

function assertType(type: 'product', entity: IProduct | ICompany): entity is IProduct;
function assertType(type: 'company', entity: IProduct | ICompany): entity is ICompany;
function assertType(type: 'product' | 'company', entity: IProduct | ICompany): entity is IProduct | ICompany {
    return entity && type === "product" || type === "company";
}
```

[Playground Link](http://www.typescriptlang.org/play/index.html?ssl=1&ssc=1&pln=27&pc=38#code/KYDwDg9gTgLgBASwHY2FAZgQwMbDgSQAUoIATAV23gG8AoOBuMEiq-UgLjiXIFsAjNAG5aAX1q1QkWIhRosuAgGEIvMJiQBPOHUZxsq9VvZceA4WInpySKgghJ9AGwTYA1gAoYmsMC4ByZjJKGH8AGjhgFARvLiIWEIBKLgBnGChkAHMRa1sYe0dsF3cvHz84fwM1DU1wyOjY5UMa5Lg0jKRs2ly7B2dXNwAeABVIkFQkUhSCYmCqOAAfJuqtAD5S3wCg1lDFiqqjWoio-MbhxJ16RgR0OA28AF4niu2Q-zgAMg+4TBSUtBgwzK92ODU0iQuuj0jCgwBg5CgjkCCXm7wA1PVTpoAHSvNikER6USRJz-RC3e5wJ4PfbNLTvL4-P4AoG+EGYmLgyFXaFwWHwxG0lbadEc7zYg41diExjiHlwGAACxIAHduMA1QBRKAkKAefwqkidWRgcihRIiOU9fJ9X7-WCs4D3LYo0KgrFxWY7Pb4FTC1onTmIabxOYwHI2XqOO0s4HeTZCw51QONUPepa+ungrgp7QIEN+w4RvIFJn2wFxsousPvJaVLPJsGe10+wstHNg4MzFsZttaS56fkIxy5z7feOPZ4AIjxMCniyWE6p08lWinlokRQG+tndWoTFdJjgAEYAEwAZjgogtQA)

### A **much** better solution (in my mind):

```js
function click(entity: IProduct | ICompany) {
    // here: (parameter) entity: IProduct | ICompany

    if ("productId" in entity) {
        // here: (parameter) entity: IProduct
        return `product ${entity.productId}`;

    } else if ("companyId" in entity) {
        // here: (parameter) entity: ICompany
        return `company ${entity.companyId}`;
    }

    throw new Error('wrong input');
}
```

[Playground Link](http://www.typescriptlang.org/play/?ssl=1&ssc=1&pln=24&pc=27#code/KYDwDg9gTgLgBASwHY2FAZgQwMbDgSQAUoIATAV23gG8AoOBuMEiq-UgLjiXIFsAjNAG5aAX1q1QkWIhRosuAgGEIvMJiQBPOHUZxsq9VvZceA4WInpySKgghJ9AGwTYA1gApgKBDE1ciFkp4AB9lQw1NAEodekYAeni4AAs0YC4PdShMXmBUKBjvGF9-AmIyYLgw-BU1SIk9BHQ4DwAiZgq2UlbZOCKSmN09BKTUqHSWrJy8tEKfPwDy1hg44bhxmHIoRwADDuW4ABJqfr8AOn3g9lEdkTXGVbhRPqcAZzwmltaDOuNu3tO0Vi9zgiRSaQyU1y%20TmxQW4V%20mkeeg2W12PyM2mOgLOGMi11uj3EjxgyRIAHduMBKQBRKAkKAeADk5JISAA5rIwOQYEyoiJidgXO4PNQmEEulwAIwAJgAzE9%20UA)

Comment: i'm not a big fan of the latter, because if in the future for whatever reason a property `productId` is added to the company entity, we're going to have unexpected side effects. Thanks for the former suggestion though!

Comment: @BartvandenBurg well, if you think about it, interfaces in TypeScript are **only** semantics. So an object that actually has a `productId` **does** implement `IProduct`. JavaScript is duck-typed. If you really want to make sure the object itself capture a type, you can either use concrete classes  and the `instanceof` keyword, or add a `type` property which will define the object type

Comment: see [Playground](http://www.typescriptlang.org/play/?ssl=1&ssc=1&pln=21&pc=2#code/KYDwDg9gTgLgBASwHY2FAZgQwMbDgSQBUBPMYAEwHkAjAK2G3gG8AoOduGU4ALjgGcYUZAHMA3CwC+LFqEixEKNFlwESZAIJxQqJOX5ruVOg2ZsOXMnwBEG6xI5wwUCGA19BwpOKky50eGRUDBw8Im4AIW0QXX1DMmN6RjhWR0teOGsI+3N2Z1cIviQAVwBbajQJaRZ0YqRGBAgkOGwm-jLgAAoIOj5wzTgAH3jgCIBKDyFRFNyBAHcEGGwACzhuugA6dLGZx0dsTH48W2s+KGAYYqhmntoN-LcHPfYDo8zss4urm82HiK2IAAZCAHAA2wAAylNvJ0xk9nuRgFhiqCYHwYMsXHM4EhgNiAKJQFxQTrWAByEECpTA4NKwCU5GscNm0kkQA)